# No matching token for number_type [BIG_INTEGER] when trying to save large number as float

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have next dynamic template for type:

```
    "dynamic_templates" : [
      {
        "$r_as_float" : {
          "match" : "*$r",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "float"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

When I try to create new document:

```
curl -XPOST es-1:9200/mydataspace_001001/type/276121/_create -d '
{
  "kbk$r": 17404121130190019244,
}
```

I receive next error:

```
{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"No matching token for number_type [BIG_INTEGER]"}
```

I have no this error when `"kbk$r": 17404` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `float` can only take a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point and 17404121130190019244 is way over that limit.

You need to either use a `double` or a `long`type instead of `float`. See the [different numeric types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html) at your disposal.

Comment: Thank you. I use JavaScript and I resolve problem by applying ```Number.prototype.toExponential()``` for this number.

Comment: ok but you're going to get a scientific exponent at the end, not sure this is what you want.

Comment: This works for me. I no need to save all digits in this number